# Retrieve Json from request.FILES in Django without writing to file

Tags: django, json, post

Have an external computer sending a POST with enctype: multipart/form-data. Packet is received by Django server.

```
print request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {u'data': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.json (application/octet-stream)>], u'sampleImage': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.jpg (application/octet-stream)>]}>
```

Current code in view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def testPost(request):    
    jsonData = None
    if request.FILES.has_key('data'):
        file = ContentFile(request.Files['data'])
        jsonData.encode(file)

    return HttpResponse(jsonData)
```

I've tried File(request.Files['data']) which also seems to end up in None. I was successful in using ImageFile for images, but no documentation on Json data. 
How is request.Files['data'] converted into a dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the content of uploaded file, you can directly use the `.read()` api.

You are assigning `jsonData` to `None` and then trying to call `encode()` method of it, which is incorrect.

Something like:

```
if request.FILES.has_key('data'):
    file = request.Files['data']
    data = file.read()
    #you have file contents in data
```